# Passing webM file as parameter in C++?

Tags: c++, stream, webm

I'm trying to write a program that accepts a webM file (media) as a parameter, and then output the stream details via TTY in as much detail as possible. I figured I'd try to open the file in binary mode, but am not sure where to start.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a very high level question, so I'll answer it as such:

If you're creating a command line program in C/C++ that needs to accept parameters, look up how to use the 'argc' and 'argv' parameters to the main() function.

Once you have the parameter being passed into your main function, you will try to open it using some file reading library (there are several to choose from based on your needs and platform). Yes, you will want to open a WebM file in binary mode if the file library cares about the difference. If using fopen(), specify "rb" to read in binary mode-- this won't make any difference on Unix (vs. plain "r") but it will make a big difference on Windows.

From there, you can start reading bytes from the WebM file and processing them. Be advised that WebM is based on the Matroska multimedia format which is quite involved. If you are doing this as an academic exercise, more power to you. If you are looking to get something accomplished on a tight deadline, there are libraries you can call to do the heavy lifting of Matroska parsing on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by making use of libwebm. The sample code is given below. It prints header, cluster, segments etc.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdbool.h"
#include "string.h"

#include <memory>
#include <mkv/mkvreader.hpp>
#include <mkv/mkvparser.hpp>
#include <mkv/mkvparser.hpp>
#include "webm_parser.h"

static const wchar_t* utf8towcs(const char* str);
bool InputHasCues(const mkvparser::Segment* const segment);

using namespace mkvparser;

/**
* This file reads an webm file. Generates a new file with random number 
* of packets in a single webm page.
*/
int webm_parse(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ret = -1;
    char *file_out;
    char *file_in;
    FILE *fd_out = NULL;
    MkvReader reader;

    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./webm <input webm file> <output webm file>\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    file_in = argv[1];
    file_out = argv[2];

    printf("\n\nInput webm file = %s , Output webm file = %s\n", file_in, file_out);

    fd_out = fopen(file_out, "w+");
    if(fd_out == NULL) goto on_error;

    if(reader.Open(file_in))
    {
        printf("Error opening input file %s", file_in);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Successfully opened input file %s\n", file_in);
    }

    webm_parse_header(&reader);

    /** Return 0 on success */
    printf("\n");
    return ret;

on_error:
    if(fd_out) fclose(fd_out);
    printf("Error while parse/generate webm file\n");

    /** Return -1 on failure */
    return -1;
}

int webm_parse_header(void *reader)
{
    int maj, min, build, rev;
    long long pos = 0;
    typedef mkvparser::Segment seg_t;
    seg_t* pSegment_;
    long long ret;
    MkvReader *mkvrdr = (MkvReader *)reader;
    EBMLHeader ebmlHeader;

    GetVersion(maj, min, build, rev);
    printf("libmkv verison: %d.%d.%d.%d\n", maj, min, build, rev);
    ebmlHeader.Parse(mkvrdr, pos);

    printf("\t\t\t    EBML Header\n");
    printf("\t\tEBML Version\t\t: %lld\n", ebmlHeader.m_version);
    printf("\t\tEBML MaxIDLength\t: %lld\n", ebmlHeader.m_maxIdLength);
    printf("\t\tEBML MaxSizeLength\t: %lld\n", ebmlHeader.m_maxSizeLength);
    printf("\t\tDoc Type\t\t: %s\n", ebmlHeader.m_docType);
    printf("\t\tPos\t\t\t: %lld\n", pos);    

    ret = seg_t::CreateInstance(mkvrdr, pos, pSegment_);
    if (ret) 
    {
        printf("Segment::CreateInstance() failed.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Segment::CreateInstance() successful.\n");
    }

    const std::auto_ptr<seg_t> pSegment(pSegment_);
    ret = pSegment->Load();
    if (ret < 0) 
    {
        printf("Segment::Load() failed.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Segment::Load() successful.\n");
    }

    const SegmentInfo* const pSegmentInfo = pSegment->GetInfo();
    const long long timeCodeScale = pSegmentInfo->GetTimeCodeScale();
    const long long duration_ns = pSegmentInfo->GetDuration();
    const char* const pTitle_ = pSegmentInfo->GetTitleAsUTF8();
    const wchar_t* const pTitle = utf8towcs(pTitle_);
    const char* const pMuxingApp_ = pSegmentInfo->GetMuxingAppAsUTF8();
    const wchar_t* const pMuxingApp = utf8towcs(pMuxingApp_);
    const char* const pWritingApp_ = pSegmentInfo->GetWritingAppAsUTF8();
    const wchar_t* const pWritingApp = utf8towcs(pWritingApp_);

    printf("\n");
    printf("\t\t\t   Segment Info\n");
    printf("\t\tTimeCodeScale\t\t: %lld \n", timeCodeScale);
    printf("\t\tDuration\t\t: %lld\n", duration_ns);

    const double duration_sec = double(duration_ns) / 1000000000;
    printf("\t\tDuration(secs)\t\t: %7.3lf\n", duration_sec);

    if (pTitle == NULL)
        printf("\t\tTrack Name\t\t: NULL\n");
    else 
    {
        printf("\t\tTrack Name\t\t: %ls\n", pTitle);
        delete[] pTitle;
    }    

    if (pMuxingApp == NULL)
        printf("\t\tMuxing App\t\t: NULL\n");
    else 
    {
        printf("\t\tMuxing App\t\t: %ls\n", pMuxingApp);
        delete[] pMuxingApp;
    }

    if (pWritingApp == NULL)
        printf("\t\tWriting App\t\t: NULL\n");
    else 
    {
        printf("\t\tWriting App\t\t: %ls\n", pWritingApp);
        delete[] pWritingApp;
    }

    // pos of segment payload
    printf("\t\tPosition(Segment)\t: %lld\n", pSegment->m_start);

    // size of segment payload
    printf("\t\tSize(Segment)\t\t: %lld\n", pSegment->m_size);

    const mkvparser::Tracks* pTracks = pSegment->GetTracks();

    unsigned long track_num = 0;
    const unsigned long num_tracks = pTracks->GetTracksCount();

    printf("\n\t\t\t   Track Info\n");


    while (track_num != num_tracks) 
    {
        const Track* const pTrack = pTracks->GetTrackByIndex(track_num++);

        if (pTrack == NULL)
        continue;

        const long trackType = pTrack->GetType();
        const long trackNumber = pTrack->GetNumber();
        const unsigned long long trackUid = pTrack->GetUid();
        const wchar_t* const pTrackName = utf8towcs(pTrack->GetNameAsUTF8());

        printf("\t\tTrack Type\t\t: %ld\n", trackType);
        printf("\t\tTrack Number\t\t: %ld\n", trackNumber);
        printf("\t\tTrack Uid\t\t: %lld\n", trackUid);

        if (pTrackName == NULL)
            printf("\t\tTrack Name\t\t: NULL\n");
        else 
        {
            printf("\t\tTrack Name\t\t: %ls \n", pTrackName);
            delete[] pTrackName;
        }

        const char* const pCodecId = pTrack->GetCodecId();

        if (pCodecId == NULL)
            printf("\t\tCodec Id\t\t: NULL\n");
        else
            printf("\t\tCodec Id\t\t: %s\n", pCodecId);

        const char* const pCodecName_ = pTrack->GetCodecNameAsUTF8();
        const wchar_t* const pCodecName = utf8towcs(pCodecName_);

        if (pCodecName == NULL)
            printf("\t\tCodec Name\t\t: NULL\n");
        else 
        {
            printf("\t\tCodec Name\t\t: %ls\n", pCodecName);
            delete[] pCodecName;
        }

        if (trackType == mkvparser::Track::kVideo) 
        {
            const VideoTrack* const pVideoTrack =
            static_cast<const VideoTrack*>(pTrack);

            const long long width = pVideoTrack->GetWidth();
            printf("\t\tVideo Width\t\t: %lld\n", width);

            const long long height = pVideoTrack->GetHeight();
            printf("\t\tVideo Height\t\t: %lld\n", height);

            const double rate = pVideoTrack->GetFrameRate();
            printf("\t\tVideo Rate\t\t: %f\n", rate);
        }

        if (trackType == mkvparser::Track::kAudio) 
        {
            const AudioTrack* const pAudioTrack =
            static_cast<const AudioTrack*>(pTrack);

            const long long channels = pAudioTrack->GetChannels();
            printf("\t\tAudio Channels\t\t: %lld\n", channels);

            const long long bitDepth = pAudioTrack->GetBitDepth();
            printf("\t\tAudio BitDepth\t\t: %lld\n", bitDepth);

            const double sampleRate = pAudioTrack->GetSamplingRate();
            printf("\t\tAddio Sample Rate\t: %.3f\n", sampleRate);

            const long long codecDelay = pAudioTrack->GetCodecDelay();
            printf("\t\tAudio Codec Delay\t: %lld\n", codecDelay);

            const long long seekPreRoll = pAudioTrack->GetSeekPreRoll();
            printf("\t\tAudio Seek Pre Roll\t: %lld\n", seekPreRoll);
        }
    }


    printf("\n\n\t\t\t   Cluster Info\n");
    const unsigned long clusterCount = pSegment->GetCount();

    printf("\t\tCluster Count\t: %ld\n\n", clusterCount);

    if (clusterCount == 0) 
    {
        printf("\t\tSegment has no clusters.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    const mkvparser::Cluster* pCluster = pSegment->GetFirst();

    while ((pCluster != NULL) && !pCluster->EOS()) 
    {
        const long long timeCode = pCluster->GetTimeCode();
        printf("\t\tCluster Time Code\t: %lld\n", timeCode);

        const long long time_ns = pCluster->GetTime();
        printf("\t\tCluster Time (ns)\t: %lld\n", time_ns);

        const BlockEntry* pBlockEntry;

        long status = pCluster->GetFirst(pBlockEntry);

        if (status < 0)  // error
        {
            printf("\t\tError parsing first block of cluster\n");
            fflush(stdout);
            return -1;
        }

        while ((pBlockEntry != NULL) && !pBlockEntry->EOS()) 
        {
            const Block* const pBlock = pBlockEntry->GetBlock();
            const long long trackNum = pBlock->GetTrackNumber();
            const unsigned long tn = static_cast<unsigned long>(trackNum);
            const Track* const pTrack = pTracks->GetTrackByNumber(tn);

            if (pTrack == NULL)
                printf("\t\t\tBlock\t\t:UNKNOWN TRACK TYPE\n");
            else 
            {
                const long long trackType = pTrack->GetType();
                const int frameCount = pBlock->GetFrameCount();
                const long long time_ns = pBlock->GetTime(pCluster);
                const long long discard_padding = pBlock->GetDiscardPadding();

                printf("\t\t\tBlock\t\t:%s,%s,%15lld,%lld\n",
                (trackType == mkvparser::Track::kVideo) ? "V" : "A",
                pBlock->IsKey() ? "I" : "P", time_ns, discard_padding);

                for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; ++i) 
                {
                    const Block::Frame& theFrame = pBlock->GetFrame(i);
                    const long size = theFrame.len;
                    const long long offset = theFrame.pos;
                    printf("\t\t\t %15ld,%15llx\n", size, offset);
                }
            }

            status = pCluster->GetNext(pBlockEntry, pBlockEntry);

            if (status < 0) 
            {
                printf("\t\t\tError parsing next block of cluster\n");
                fflush(stdout);
                return -1;
            }
        }
        pCluster = pSegment->GetNext(pCluster);
    }

    if (InputHasCues(pSegment.get())) 
    {
        // Walk them.
        const mkvparser::Cues* const cues = pSegment->GetCues();
        const mkvparser::CuePoint* cue = cues->GetFirst();
        int cue_point_num = 1;

        printf("\t\tCues\n");
        do 
        {
            for (track_num = 0; track_num < num_tracks; ++track_num) 
            {
                const mkvparser::Track* const track =
                        pTracks->GetTrackByIndex(track_num);

                const mkvparser::CuePoint::TrackPosition* const track_pos =
                        cue->Find(track);

                if (track_pos != NULL) 
                {
                    const char track_type =
                    (track->GetType() == mkvparser::Track::kVideo) ? 'V' : 'A';
                    printf(
                        "\t\t\tCue Point %4d Track %3lu(%c) Time %14lld "
                        "Block %4lld Pos %8llx\n",
                        cue_point_num, track->GetNumber(), track_type,
                        cue->GetTime(pSegment.get()), track_pos->m_block,
                        track_pos->m_pos);
                }
            }
            cue = cues->GetNext(cue);
            ++cue_point_num;

        } while (cue != NULL);
    }

    const mkvparser::Tags* const tags = pSegment->GetTags();
    if (tags && tags->GetTagCount() > 0) 
    {
        printf("\t\tTags\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < tags->GetTagCount(); ++i) 
        {
            const mkvparser::Tags::Tag* const tag = tags->GetTag(i);
            printf("\t\t\tTag\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < tag->GetSimpleTagCount(); j++) 
            {
                const mkvparser::Tags::SimpleTag* const simple_tag =
                    tag->GetSimpleTag(j);
                printf("\t\t\t\tSimple Tag \"%s\" Value \"%s\"\n",
                    simple_tag->GetTagName(), simple_tag->GetTagString());
            }
        }
    }

    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;

on_error:
    return -1;
}

static const wchar_t* utf8towcs(const char* str) 
{
    if (str == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // TODO: this probably requires that the locale be
    // configured somehow:

    const size_t size = mbstowcs(NULL, str, 0);

    if (size == 0)
        return NULL;

    wchar_t* const val = new wchar_t[size + 1];

    mbstowcs(val, str, size);
    val[size] = L'\0';

    return val;
}

bool InputHasCues(const mkvparser::Segment* const segment) 
{
    const mkvparser::Cues* const cues = segment->GetCues();
    if (cues == NULL)
        return false;

    while (!cues->DoneParsing())
        cues->LoadCuePoint();

    const mkvparser::CuePoint* const cue_point = cues->GetFirst();
    if (cue_point == NULL)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```